# Python string.strip stripping too many characters

Tags: python

I am using Python 3 to process file names, and this is my code:

```
name = 'movies.csv'
table_name = name.strip(".csv")
```

The expected value of table_name should be "movies" yet table_name keeps returning "movie".

Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`strip()` removes all the leading and trailing characters from the input string that match one of the characters in the parameter string:

```
>>> "abcdefabcdefabc".strip("cba")
'defabcdef'
```

You want to use a regex: `table_name = re.sub(r"\.csv$", "", name)` or `os.path`s path manipulation functions:

```
>>> table_name, extension = os.path.splitext("movies.csv")
>>> table_name
'movies'
>>> extension
'.csv'
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a lazy way that appears to work fine too (assuming all the files from which you want to retrieve the names are CSV files):

```
if name.endswith('.csv'):    
    table_name = name.rstrip("csv").rstrip(".")
```

The `strip()` method removes all the leading/trailing characters that match those inside the parentheses. Therefore, the idea in this approach is to:

1. Remove the `csv` extension - since there is a `.` we know `rstrip()` will stop searching there. This will leave us with the `movies.` string.
2. Remove the `.` from the `movies.` string - the `rstrip()` will only look for trailing dots.

**Why `rstrip()`**: Since we know that the text to be removed is in the end of the string, we can specify `rstrip` for better control (i.e. to avoid unintentionally removing any eventual leading `c`, `s` or `v` characters).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve the filename without extension, you have the `os.path.splitext` [function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

```
>>> import os
>>> name, extension = os.path.splitext("movies.csv")
>>> name
'movies'
```